# Initializing struct

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have written struct.

```
struct linesHor
{
    var line = CAShapeLayer()
    var linePath = UIBezierPath()
    var beginX : CGFloat
    var endX : CGFloat
    var lastY : CGFloat
    var point1 = CGPoint.zero
    var point2 = CGPoint.zero
    init(){
        beginX = 0
        endX = 0
        lastY = 0
    }
}
```

I have made array of this struct.

```
var linesHorisontal = [linesHor]()
```

When I am trying to access struct field of array, I get 'out of range' exception.

```
linesHorisontal[0].point1 = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height/2)
linesHorisontal[0].beginX = 0
```

Comment: You're attempting to set the first element of an array that has no elements.

Comment: @Alexander What is the right way of creating an array that has elements?

Comment: You can use an array literal if you need a fixed set of elements (most preferable), preallocate an array with a certain number of elements and adjust them after (which is usually not desirable), or you use methods that add new elements, like `append` and `prepend`. Read https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you probably haven't added any elements to your array so you are indexing out of bounds. You have created the array with a type of `linesHor` but you now need to fill it with values.

This works:

```
var linesHorisontal = [linesHor]()
var lh = linesHor()
linesHorisontal.append(lh)

linesHorisontal[0].point1 = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
linesHorisontal[0].beginX = 0
```

or

```
var linesHorisontal = [linesHor()]

linesHorisontal[0].point1 = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
linesHorisontal[0].beginX = 0
```

The second example creates your struct and then places it in the first spot in an array. The first example creates an empty array with no elements of type `linesHor`.

Answer (score 0):

This creates an array with no elements:

```
var linesHorisontal = [linesHor]()
```

`[linesHor]` is the type and you add `()` to create a new instance of it. A new array by default has no elements. When you try to access the first element, it is only natural that it crashes.

To create an array with one `linesHor` inside is like this:

```
var linesHorisontal = [linesHor()]
```

`[]` denotes an array literal and inside it, there is a `linesHor()`. `linesHor()` creates a new instance of `linesHor`.

It's interesting to see how changing the position of `()` changes everything :)